# Cannot resolve caller sqlite3_bind: Do not understand this error in my Perl 6 script

Tags: sqlite, raku

Purpose of script: I want to be able to use it to insert expenses into a SQLite database and then make custom reports later to pull out information so I can budget my expenses better.

I do not understand this error code at all.

> `perl6 budgetpro.p6`
>
> Apple
>
> An apple a day keeps the doctor away
>
> Hi, I am Essential, nice to meet you, Eggman
>
> ```
> Cannot resolve caller sqlite3_bind(DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT, Int,
> Date); none of these signatures match:
>     (DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT $stmt, Int $n, Blob:D $b)
>     (DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT $stmt, Int $n, Real:D $d)
>     (DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT $stmt, Int $n, Int:D $i)
>     (DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT $stmt, Int $n, Any:U)
>     (DBDish::SQLite::Native::STMT $stmt, Int $n, Str:D $d)   
>     in method execute at /home/jon/opt/rakudo-star/share/perl6/site/sources/2D749062AA6D5641452CDA214FC7C566E7E3E2A1
> (DBDish::SQLite::StatementHandle) line 38
>     in method insert at budgetpro.p6 line 54   in block <unit> at budgetpro.p6 line 86`
> ```

```
  2
  3 use v6;
  4 use DBIish;
  5
  6 constant DB = 'budgetpro.sqlite3';
  7 my $dbh = DBIish.connect('SQLite', database => DB);
  8
  9 #$dbh.do('drop table if exists Essential, Savings, Personal');
 10
 11 sub create-schema {
 12     $dbh.do(qq:to/SCHEMA/);
 13         create table if not exists Essential(
 14             id          integer primary key not null,
 15             name        varchar not null,
 16             quantity    integer not null,
 17             price       numeric(5,2) not null,
 18             description varchar not null,
 19             date        timestamp not null default (datetime('now'))
 20         );
 21         create table is not exists Savings(
 22             id          integer primary key not null,
 23             name        varchar not null,
 24             quantity    integer not null,
 25             price       numeric(5,2) not null,
 26             description varchar not null,
 27             date        timestamp not null default (datetime('now'))
 28         );
 29         create table if not exists Personal(
 30             id          integer primary key not null,
 31             name        varchar not null,
 32             quantity    integer not null,
 33             price       numeric(5,2) not null,
 34             description varchar not null,
 35             date        timestamp not null default (datetime('now'))
 36         );
 37     SCHEMA
 38 }
 39
 40 create-schema;
 41
 42 class Item {
 43     has $!table = 'Essential';
 44     has $.name;
 45     has $.quantity;
 46     has $.price;
 47     has $.description is rw;
 48     has $.timestamp;
 49     has Str $.notes is rw;
 50     method notes() { "$!notes\n" };
 51
 52     method insert($name, $quantity?, $price?, $description?, $timestamp?) {
 53         my $sth = $dbh.prepare("insert into Essential(name,quantity,price,description,date) values (?,?,?,?,?)");
 54         $sth.execute($name, $quantity, $price, $description, $timestamp);
 55
 56         say "Inserted $name, $quantity, $price, $description, $timestamp";
 57     }
 58 }
 59
 60 class Essential is Item {
 61     method greet($me: $person) {
 62         say "Hi, I am $me.^name(), nice to meet you, $person";
 63     }
 64 }
 65
 66 class Savings is Item {
 67 }
 68
 69 class Personal is Item {
 70 }
 71 
 72 my $food = Essential.new(
 73     name => 'Apple',
 74     price => .99,
 75     quantity => 2,
 76     notes => 'An apple a day keeps the doctor away'
 77 );
 78
 79 say $food.name;
 80 say $food.notes;
 81 Essential.new.greet('Eggman');
 82 say '';
 83
 84 my $test = Item.new();
 85
 86 $test.insert("Cheese", 2, 1.99, 'Block of cheddar', Date.new(now));
 87
 88 say $test.name;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you called:

```perl6
$test.insert("Cheese", 2, 1.99, 'Block of cheddar', Date.new(now));
```

That eventually calls `sqlite3_bind`, but there isn't a candidate that accepts an instance of `Date` as the third argument.

---

It would accept an instance of a `Blob`, `Int`, `Real` (`Numeric` but not `Complex`), or `Str`. It would also accept an undefined value (`Any:U`).

It seems to me that it is a bug or missing feature in the database driver that it doesn't accept a `DateTime` or perhaps even an `Instant` object, and automatically translates that to what SQLite expects.

---

I would also like to point out there is `Date.today` and `DateTime.now`. The latter of which will keep track of the current timezone information while `DateTime.new(now)` won't.
(This is intentional, as there is no way to know where the `Instant` came from.)

Answer (score 6):

@Brad Gilbert is right. Statements admit only 5 kinds of data structures, and none of them is `Date`. [`TIME` and `DATE` are standard data types in SQL](http://www-db.deis.unibo.it/courses/TW/DOCS/w3schools/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp.html), but for the time being they don't seem to have support in DBIish. In this case, you can just change line 85 to

```
$test.insert("Cheese", 2, 1.99, 'Block of cheddar', Date.new(now).Str);
```

and let your program handle conversion to and from dates, you'll have to change the definition of the `Essential` table, too. You can also let the database handle default values. You will have to eliminate "not null", because it conflicts with the `default` sentence.

There are also a number of minor errors. This, reduced to the minimum expression, works and inserts the default timestamp correctly into the database (as checked by using sqlite3 command line):

```
use v6;
use DBIish;

constant DB = 'budgetpro.sqlite3';
my $dbh = DBIish.connect('SQLite', database => DB);

#$dbh.do('drop table if exists Essential, Savings, Personal');

sub create-schema {
    $dbh.do(qq:to/SCHEMA/);
        create table if not exists Essential(
            id          integer primary key not null,
            name        varchar not null,
            quantity    integer not null,
            price       numeric(5,2) not null,
            description varchar not null,
            date        timestamp default (datetime('now'))
        );
    SCHEMA
}

create-schema;

class Item {
    has $!table = 'Essential';
    has $.name;
    has $.quantity;
    has $.price;
    has $.description is rw;
    has $.timestamp;
    has Str $.notes is rw;
    method notes() { "$!notes\n" };

    method insert($name, $quantity?, $price?, $description?, $timestamp?) {
        my $sth = $dbh.prepare("insert into Essential(name,quantity,price,description) values (?,?,?,?)");
        $sth.execute($name, $quantity, $price, $description);

        say "Inserted $name, $quantity, $price, $description";
    }
}

Item.new().insert("Cheese", 2, 1.99, 'Block of cheddar');
```

Please note that your `Item` class is not actually instantiated by running an `insert` sentence, and thus `$test.name` in the last line would just return an empty object with default values assigned to instance variables. You might want to change the `insert` method to a submethod that instantiates the item *and* inserts it into the database.

Comment: I'm questioning my decision over making the tables in my database classes. Is this worth it?

Comment: Well, it's sensible to make every item a database object from the architectural point of view. But at the end of the day, if it makes things more complicated for you, maybe it's not worth the while.

Comment: I want to learn good OO design, and this project is a part of challenging myself. If you have any links or advice in regard to this, then I will gladly eat it up :)

Comment: You've got of course the [classes and objects tutorial](https://docs.perl6.org/language/classtut). Perl 6 has a very complete implementation of most things in the object orientation book, including traits (called Roles). But your project is a good start, only bear in mind that classes are tables, objects are rows, and you're probably good to go.